# Complex Number Multiplication resulting in Zero

Tags: complex-numbers

The product of two complex numbers is zero only when the modulus of one (or both) of the complex numbers is zero. True or false?

My intuition is that this is true, since the modulus, when written in trigonometric form, is $r$, so $z*w = r_1[cos(\theta_1)+isin(\theta_1)]r_2[cos(\theta_2)+isin(\theta_2)]$. Simplifying, we get $r_1 r_2 [cis(\theta_1 + \theta_2)]$ and either $r_1$ or $r_2$ must be $0$ for the product itself to be $0$. Is this rigorous enough?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Maybe you should explain why $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ can't be $0$

Comment: For the purpose of just answering the true false, the complex numbers are famously known to be a field, and fields are just a special case of integral domains, and [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory)) are precisely those rings with the stated property that $ab=0\iff a=0\vee b=0$

Comment: true, but not the case for split-complex numbers and dual numbers.

Comment: Because those fail to be integral domains (*precisely for that reason*).  Letting $j$ be the split-complex imaginary unit satisfying $j^2=1$, we have $(1+j)(1-j)=1-j^2=1-1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:
$$|z\cdot w|=|r_1|\cdot|r_2|\cdot|\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1|\cdot|\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2|=|r_1|\cdot|r_2|\cdot 1\cdot 1$$
Then, if $|z\cdot w|=0$, at least one of the factors must be $0$.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for the correction. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

**To Prove**: $~|z| \times |w| = |z \times w| ~: z,w \in \Bbb{C}.$

Sufficient to show that $|z|^2 \times |w|^2 = |z \times w|^2.$

Let $z = (x + iy), w = (u + iv).$

$|z|^2 \times |w|^2 = (x^2 + y^2)(u^2 + v^2).$

$|z \times w|^2$ 
$= |(x + iy)(u + iv)|^2 $ 
$= |(xu - yv) + i(xv + yu)|^2 $ 
$= (xu - yv)^2 + (xv + yu)^2 $ 
$= x^2u^2 + y^2v^2 - 2xuyv + x^2v^2 + y^2u^2 + 2xvyu $ 
$= x^2u^2 + y^2v^2 + x^2v^2 + y^2u^2 $ 
$= (x^2 + y^2)(u^2 + v^2)$ 
$= |z|^2 \times |w|^2.$